# Is there a reason to host an English speaking audience targeted website in the USA?

Tags: web-hosting, dedicated-hosting

I am running an international project for English learners and currently choosing a hosting provider. USA hosting is much more expensive than one I can find in Europe and site's potential visitors are located world-wide (but mostly in USA of course).

Is there a solid reason to pay for USA hosting in terms of visibility for SE(s), visitor comfort, etc? Or I can start up with european hosting and scale globally later if numbers start matching?

Comment: See also: [Web hosting country effect site SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58503/web-hosting-country-effect-site-seo) and [Where should webhosting be located when focusing on the US and EU markets?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78050/where-should-webhosting-be-located-when-focusing-on-the-us-and-eu-markets)